# Two sounds on one click, Second with deley

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to solve following problem. I have a menu that when you click produces a sound. What i want to do is to have play one sound on click then after some delay second sound plays.
Here is the code co far.

```
    var beepOne = $("#beep")[0];
$("h3").click(function() {
        beepOne.play();
    });

var beepTwo = $("#beep-conf")[0];
var beepThree = $("#beep-off")[0];
$("a").click(function() {
        beepTwo.play();
        beepThree.play();
    });
```

Comment: How about `setTimeout(function(){ beepThree.play() }, 2000 )`?

Comment: Or even `setTimeout( beepThree.play , 2000 )`, thanks A.Wolff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timeout for the second play():

```
$("a").click(function() {
    beepTwo.play();
    setTimeout(function(){
        beepThree.play()
    },200) //time in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Doml The-Bread - Thank you kind sir. That worked with one minor correction. },200);

Comment: ah yeah, sorry! changed it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(function(){ toDoIn1000ms(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Or just `setTimeout( toDoIn1000ms, 1000)`

Comment: Really? Will this actually play? You're not executing the function, I'm not sure it will work, will it?

Comment: Damn, thinking about it, that makes sense. I never saw it this way :)

Comment: @JeremyThille I just tested it, gives illegal invocation :(

Comment: @JeremyThille I see, this is regarding context: `setTimeout(beepThree.play.bind(beepThree), 2000);`  So your way is more readable imo